# CSS bubble conversation losing format with long texts

Tags: html, css

I have a bubble conversation like the following:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
}

ul li {
  max-width: 50vw;
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background: #eee;
}

.you {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.me {
  grid-column: 2/4
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="myConversation" class="afterheader">
    <li class="me">1234</li>
    <li class="me">44</li>
    <li class="me">333</li>
    <li class="me">333</li>
    <li class="you">33</li>
      <li class="me">254</li>
      <li class="me">21345</li>
      <li class="me">long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It is working great with short texts but with longer texts it is losing the bubble format.

Right side is the desired functionality.
Left side is an example of the malfunction with long texts:

[image]

How can avoid it? (`display:grid` property is mandatory in this case)

Comment: Have you tried using max-width?

Comment: Please explain what the desired functionality is when there's long text. As Skye points out, it seems like you're just missing a `max-width`.

Comment: Which row correct and which is incorrect?

Comment: @Rojo My interpretation is that it's supposed to work like a common SMS conversation. The image on the right shows the correct version, where all of the messages on the right are from one person, and the one message on the left ("33") is from another. However, if the messages get too long, they occupy the full width, and it's no longer clear (other than the border) who is sending which messages.

Comment: I have edited my question for better understanding. @Rojo coment is right

Comment: See [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width). :)

Comment: max-width is not working

Comment: @Alfonso_MA What are you setting it to? It works fine for me, e.g., `ul li { ... max-width: 50vw; ... }`.

Comment: @Alfonso_MA You never ended the element `<li class='you'>`. This could be part of the problem...

Comment: @Rojo I have added the max-width property to the question. It is 'working' but the 'me' messages are in the middle of the body width, not justify to the right side of the body. You can Run code snipped in the question and check

Comment: I think you have to define how many columns there are in your grid, don't you? If you have 4 columns, you've defined `you` to start in column 1 and end in column 4, and you've defined `me` to start in column 2 and end in column 4. So it's going to overlap...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a matter of defining the grid ahead of time, and making sure you're spanning the correct number of columns.

Here's how I would do it:

1. Define a total of 4 columns.
2. Make `you` span columns 1-3.
3. Make `me` span columns 2-4.
4. ...
5. Profit?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  background: #eee;
}

.you {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.me {
  grid-column: 2/5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="myConversation" class="afterheader">
    <li class="me">1234</li>
    <li class="me">44</li>
    <li class="me">333</li>
    <li class="me">333</li>
    <li class="you">33</li>
    <li class="me">254</li>
    <li class="me">21345</li>
    <li class="me">long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```